When to use await Task.Run() and when to await an async method directly
I have seen several posts on this topic but the answers are complicated.  Suppose I have the following code:
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await Task.Run(LongRunningTask1);  

    await LongRunningTask2();

    await Task.Run(LongRunningTask2);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void LongRunningTask1()
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}

static async Task LongRunningTask2()
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}

Console.ReadLine();

Each of the above await expressions does the same thing.
Can someone give me a simplified summary of when you would use each one?
Also, which of the three await expressions create a separate thread? I assume that it is the first and third. If the second uses only the UI thread, then how is the execution time apportioned between Main() and the awaited task?
I have read that the second choice slows down the GUI (if, for example, Main() were instead a button click handler for a WinForms program).  Then why use the second choice?  What does it buy me?

Dedicate 1-2 weekends to this first

Side note, if LongRunningTask2 returns a Task, you're better of using [await] Task.Delay(###) instead of Thread.Sleep(###).

The LongRunningTask2 should give you a compilation warning about an async method that has no await inside.

I think I have the partial answer.  We use "await Task.Run(LongRunningTask1); " when we want to await a synchronous method and we use the other two choices for asynchronous methods.  However, how do we decide between the two choices for asynchronous methods?  I suppose that calling Task.Run() may incur more startup cost because a thread must be created.  Acalling the async task directly so as to lease time on the main thread

@Richard the Task.Run doesn't create a new thread. It uses a ThreadPool thread. The ThreadPool is a small self-maintained pool of reusable threads, so typically each thread in the pool will be used multiple times during its lifetime. The initial cost of creating a thread is amortized among multiple workloads.

I understand the use of the thread pool to save resources.  However, I am still unsure as to when we would await an async method using Task.Run() (in which case it goes on a separate thread) and when we would call the async method directly, in which case, it would lease time on the main thread.  One example is in a button handler.  We would await the async button handler method directly but then in the handler we would await with Task.Run() the compute-bound method. Are there any other thoughts on this? How do I know of much of the main thread I am consuming?

@Richard it's quite simple. Whatever is called with Task.Run is invoked on the ThreadPool. Whatever is called directly (without Task.Run) is invoked on the current thread. We use the Task.Run when we want to invoke something on the ThreadPool, and then await for its completion. If we didn't care about its completion we can just use the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem.

Thanks for your comment.  Can any give a simple example as to when we would use Task.Run() versus when we would call the async method directly?

I found what I was looking for.  See the section "Recognize CPU-bound and I/O-bound work" in the link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios.  If your code is I/O bound, then call the async task directly, if your code is compute bound then use Task.Run()

@Richard I have posted an answer here, that includes an example.

Thanks for the link to your example.  I think I am ready to close this incident.  Thanks to all who participated.
